# Can only use Scapy in interactive mode?

Tags: python, scapy

I just want to do -

```
from scapy import *

target = "42.42.42.42"
packet = IP()/UDP()
packet.dst = target

del pak[IP].chksum
del pak[TCP].chksum

pak.show2()
```

But "IP()" and "UDP()" are not defined.

If I use scapy.all it hands me this;

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\scapy_stuff.py", line 1, in <module>
    import scapy.all
  File "C:\Python25\Lib\site-packages\scapy\all.py", line 13, in <module>
    from arch import *
  File "C:\Python25\lib\site-packages\scapy\arch\__init__.py", line 75, in <module>
    from windows import *
  File "C:\Python25\Lib\site-packages\scapy\arch\windows\__init__.py", line 19, in <module>
    from scapy.arch import pcapdnet
  File "C:\Python25\lib\site-packages\scapy\arch\pcapdnet.py", line 157, in <module>
    import dnet
ImportError: No module named dnet
```

Everywhere I look people are just using interactive mode, I am starting to believe this is the only way.

Comment: Did you install libdnet and all the other packages needed?  (http://www.secdev.org/projects/scapy/doc/installation.html#windows)

Comment: im retarded, sorry. thanks for the link. ill do that. i figured out how to import IP and UDP though; http://pastie.org/6001804

Comment: should i close this question? (how do i?)

Comment: i did that (installed the other packages), and now; http://pastie.org/6001904

Comment: This is really hard to tell what you're missing, and it doesn't help that you're trying to run this in Python 2.7 using the 2.5 packages.

Comment: the file is just located in Python27 folder, am using 2.5

Comment: I cant remember, and i dont have the same environment at my disposal, so i cant test if this fixes it. Thank you though.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to do a `from scapy.all import *`.

All detailed on the SecDev documentation, [Using Scapy to build your own tools](http://www.secdev.org/projects/scapy/build_your_own_tools.html).

You can either import the entire scapy.all namespace, or import specifically what you need.

For the dnet issue, try this configuration where is is appropriate for your Scapy installation.

```
Change "scapy.config.conf.use_dnet = 1" to equal = 0
```

Depending on your system, it is either in scapy/arch/unix.py or scapy/arch/pcapdnet.py