# How to send packets in python?

Tags: python, scapy

I tried this piece of code for sending packet using scapy in python

```
data= "University of texas at San Antonio"
a=IP(dst="129.132.2.21")/TCP()/Raw(load=data)
sendp(a)
```

But I'm getting error in third line "sendp(a)" saying

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "<pyshell#7>", line 1, in <module>
     sendp(a)
   File "C:\Python25\lib\site-packages\scapy\sendrecv.py", line 259, in sendp
     __gen_send(conf.L2socket(iface=iface, *args, **kargs), x, inter=inter, loop=loop, 
   count=count, verbose=verbose, realtime=realtime)
   File "C:\Python25\lib\site-packages\scapy\arch\pcapdnet.py", line 313, in __init__
     self.outs = dnet.eth(iface)
   File "dnet.pyx", line 112, in dnet.eth.__init__
   OSError: No such file or directory
```

Please let me know where am I wrong.

Comment: What error are you getting? Please include complete code & complete error traceback.

Comment: Edit your question and add the error/traceback please.

Comment: `scapy` is not correctly installed: it looks for `dnet.pyx` and can't find it. I think you'll need to install `dnet`.

Comment: This should answer your question about how to use dnet [Can only use Scapy in interactive mode?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14638271/can-only-use-scapy-in-interactive-mode)

Comment: @Evert I have downloaded the dnet-1.12.win32-py2.5 and installed selecting "run as administrator". Still getting the same error. I am working on python 2.5.1

Comment: It's not `dnet` (what I figure from [here](http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.security.scapy.general/3593)). You're trying to open a device that's non-existant, and then dnet throws an OSError. Probably something that it can open the default device (whatever that is); try using another device.

Comment: I am not getting which device you talking about. Can you name it or provding link for it would be helpful for me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are using `sendp()` directly with `IP` packets, which is wrong.

Use either `sendp(Ether()/IP()/...)` or `send(IP()/...)`.

By the way, you don't need to add `Raw(load=...)`, as Scapy treats `str` as `Raw`.

So try this:

```
data = "University of texas at San Antonio"
a = IP(dst="129.132.2.21")/TCP()/data
send(a)
```